# Посоветуйте хороший способ деплоить GIT-репозиторий в корень веб-сервера

Tags: apache, git, php

Доброго времени суток.

Собственно просто уже стоит поперек горла проблема деплоя репозитория в корень домена.
На данный момент деплой происходит следующим образом:
Весь корень сервера это один большой GIT-репозиторий, но при этом сам репозиторий находится в home пользователя git (gitolite как менеджер репозиториев).
Сразу видны минусы. Например, папка wordpress это соответственно wordpress, test - папка для тестов итп. То есть если нужно обновить движок wordpress, то либо придется доводить все остальные подпроекты до вменяемого состояния, либо каждый раз делать выборочные коммиты файлов. Сам деплой происходит в post-recieve хуке командой

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/ git checkout -f
find /var/www/ -name .ssh -prune -o -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777
```

То есть сделали чекаут, выставили права, чтобы apache не падал от недостатка прав доступа к файлам, потому что хук исполняется от пользователя git, а apache от www-data.
Все в принципе хорошо ровно до тех пор, пока через веб-морду WordPress не зальешь файлы или картинки, потому что хук потом падает от недостатка прав.
Приходится из-под рута делать `chown`, но так как это происходит редко, то не особо смущает.

Естественно хочется, чтобы один подпроект был одним репозиторием, для упрощения коммитов и тестов.

Пока идея такова:
написать скрипт, который положить в корень сервера, он будет принимать на вход

- папку которую нужно скопировать (указывает на репозиторий)
- папку куда копировать (указывает например на `/wordpress/`)
- файлы, которые надо игнорировать
- папки из которых не нужно удалять лишние файлы (ну то есть в коммите их нет, а на сервере есть)

Имея такой скрипт можно просто в post-recieve хуке записать

```
wget http://localhost/deploy.php?source=...&target=...&...
```

Плюсы очевидны, `deploy.php` будет запущен от www-data, а значит у всех файлов будут нормальные права, где git никак не будет фигурировать.

Честно говоря, за то время, пока я пишу этот вопрос, я бы уже наверно написал `deploy.php`, если бы меня не смутило одно:
**а не собираюсь ли я написать велосипед ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наиболее простым мне способом показался такой:

1. Добавляем пользователя `git` в группу `www-data`

   ```
   usermod -a -G www-data git
   ```
2. Создаем новую папку для репозитория куда будет происходить деплой с владельцем `git` и группой `www-data`
3. Репозиторию создаем хук `post-receive`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   pathTo='/var/www/pathToDeploy'
   repo='testing.git'
   git --work-tree=$pathTo --git-dir=/home/git/repositories/$repo checkout -f
   cd $pathTo
   chmod -R 776 *
   chgrp -R www-data $pathTo
   ```

В итоге при добавлении нового репозитория, который надо деплоить в веб-сервер нужно просто создать папку куда деплоить, скопировать из какого-нибудь другого репозитория хук и изменить в нем `pathTo` и `repo`.

Answer (score 1):

Ну пока задача не сложноя вполне можно и deploy.php обойтись.
А так мне нравится капистрано [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/110021/) вроде неплохо расписанно

Comment: Спасибо, а как обстоят дела с владельцем файлов? Кому принадлежат файлы, которые сдеплоены в рабочий каталог веб-сервера ?

Answer (score 1):

делайте git pull из-под того юзера, что гоняет вебсервер, а потом rsync с исключениями. либо rsync с localhost с ключем. хук можно повесить на inotify, либо  через unix socket. (это сразу снимает вопрос с тормозами при push) ещё сделайте очередь если тех кто может пушить в вебсервер больше одного, я вот прям недавно приводил пример скрипта на базе которого всё это можно сделать минут за 20, ещё вариант - делать сразу pull с измененной директорией git (при клонировании можно указать) тогда будет создан   файл .git в котором будет указана эта директория (но очередь всё равно нужна).